# Checking out a branch included some untracked files

Tags: git

I have run into a problem where, when I check out a branch from my repository, a bunch of files show up that are marked as "untracked", which means they shouldn't have been in the repository in the first place.

If I delete them locally, then my git client shows those files as having been removed and I'm supposed to check in that "change".

On the other hand if I "remove" one through git and try to stage it, I get a message that the file didn't match anything.

The only thing I can say about these files is that some of the characters have accents (they're named in french) and I suspect that's what's screwing things up.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a screen shot showing this problem
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you get the same problem from the command line?

Comment: Did any of these files exist before you checked out this branch?

Comment: What `git status <path to the file in question>` command executed inside the repo tells?